# calculate difference between two date with php time() function in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched about this but I could not find anything.

I have a article table. when I write new article I write time into mysql table with using php time() function.

my table is

id article time

time data type is INT(UNSIGNED)

my problem is I want to show articles from last week to today or from last month to today.

how my mysql query should be?

normally I do this

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY Time DESC
```

so this gives me data from today to past. how should I do this? I can't come up with a solution. should I use php-mysql together or can I handle this with only mysql? could you give me idea or example please? thanks.

edit:

I changed to datetime as suggested and now I think I have timezone problem

now my ago() function work 2 hours late.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul'); //timezone function 
ago($time)
{
   $periods = array("saniye", "dakka", "saat", "gün", "hafta", "ay", "yıl", "baya");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

       $difference     = $now - $time;
       $tense         = "önce";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   return "$difference $periods[$j] önce ";
} //ago function 

echo $Date = ago(strtotime($data['WriteTime'])). 'önce';
?>
```

Comment: `time` is an `int`? Is it at least a Unix stamp? Change your table to use `time` data type.

Comment: As @njk already suggested: Use a `Date`- or `DateTime`-column and then let MySQL do _everything_ (means: don't use `time()` at all: It's not required).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `time` column is a Unix timestamp, you can try something like this: (not tested)

```
SELECT ... 
FROM magic
WHERE `time` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()
```

For your month, you would use `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`. Please, convert your column to common data types and don't use reserved words as the column names.

Answer (score 1):

First make `time` a `date type field` 
(and give it a meaningful different name like `article_date` for e.g)

Then use this query:

```
SELECT  * FROM    articles 
WHERE   article_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you made a beginner mistake in using the unix timestamp integer for storage in your database.  You should almost always use a date/datetime field type, because you invariably need to query against those fields which is much easier when not using unix timestamps.

So, convert your field to datetime, use MySQL's `NOW()` to insert current timestamps into the field when adding rows.

Then look at the MySQL data/time functions to query against thus field to your heart's desire.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @ErdemEce Perhaps look at the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function in MySQL. You could easily have all this data calculated for you in MySQL and not have to worry about different timezone setting between your application and MySQL.  Something like `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, your_field, NOW()), TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, your_field, NOW()), TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, your_field, NOW()), TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, your_field, NOW()), etc.`